# Hair particles are not moving at all

Tags: particles, hair

I've created a hairstyle with 4 particle systems. two of the particle systems work normally but the other two move at all. It budge at all. Even if I animate the mesh, the particle system will not move at all. It will act as if hair dynamics is not enabled.
I've tried baking, deleting, baking again. Redoing the particle system, messing with the collision object but nothing seems to work and there are no answers on the web. None of them pertain to a particle system not moving AT ALL.

Can anyone please help before i lose my mind?!

Here's my hair dynamic settings. Its pretty much the default blender settings.
[image]

Here's a simplified file. [Click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zNDtrQ-I20_VKsLuucBRns81peqCx4BO/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi and welcome :) Can you please [edit] your Q and add some images that show your particle settings? Are you using any forces in your scene? You may also add a simplified version of your [file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) for other users to look at as well. Thanks :)

Comment: @Timaroberts I updated the question and no im not using any forces in my scene